# Is this Lazy<T> considered a singleton?

Tags: c#, azure, singleton, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

I need to be able to call this method

```
IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();
```

From anywhere on my application, I got this connection helper class from some azure page

```
public class CacheConnectionHelper
    {
        private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(SettingsHelper.AzureRedisCache);
        });

        public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
        {
            get
            {
                return lazyConnection.Value;
            }
        }
    }
```

The question is:

1. Is the above singleton and if not how should I change it, so that each time that  I try get a Connection, its only using one instance and doesnt try to open more than one connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's a singleton because `Lazy<T>` makes sure that your factory delegate

```
return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(SettingsHelper.AzureRedisCache);
```

...is only invoked once. It will be invoked the first time `lazyConnection.Value` is read. Remaining invocations will return the same value/instance that was returned from the first invocation (it is cached).

For clarity, I would make `CacheConnectionHelper` static:

```
public static class CacheConnectionHelper
```

By the way, it looks like your code is copied from [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690521.aspx#Connect).

> This provides a thread-safe way to initialize only a **single** connected ConnectionMultiplexer instance.

Comment: so if I put this on Global.asax App Start IDatabase cache = CacheConnectionHelper.Connection.GetDatabase();, and then I put the same line everywhere then it will use the same connection opened when the application started! right?

Comment: Sure, have a look here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331(v=vs.110).aspx

, and here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997286(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Correct, it is singleton.

Reference : [using .NET 4's Lazy type](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

> If you're using .NET 4 (or higher), you can use the System.Lazy
>   type to make the laziness really simple. All you need to do is pass a
>   delegate to the constructor which calls the Singleton constructor -
>   which is done most easily with a lambda expression.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
        new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

    public static Singleton Instance { get { return lazy.Value; } }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }
}
```

It also allows you to check whether or not the instance has been created yet with the [IsValueCreated property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642334.aspx), if you need that.